# Setting datetime to a specific date by specific way

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, c#-4.0

I have a variable with date time which I have to set on a specific date by these rukles and scenarios:

- The API that I connect to has a daily limit and once that limit is reached I have to wait until NEXT DAY until 9:10 AM CEST <= This is very important

So I've been simply doing this:

```
  var localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time"));
  var tomorrowAt0910 = localTime.AddDays(1).Date + new TimeSpan(9, 10, 0);
```

And I have realized that this code has a bug, because I can have following scenarios:

- Let's say my application would expire on 30th of July at 15:00 PM in which case this logic up there would be VALID

BUT

We have a next following scenario which is more likely to happen:

- Application expires on 31st of July 5:00 AM, in which case this logic is faulty because RENEWAL DATE will be set to 1st of August 9:10AM WHICH IS BAD

If the application expires in this second case, I should set the date to same day and few hours difference (from 5AM to 9AM)

How could I do this?

Comment: Check if the expire time occurs before 9:10. If so do not add a day to localtime.

Comment: Quick thought: Instead of adding 1 day, add the hours minus the datetime offset for your local timezone.

Comment: @VDWWD Could you show me an example?

Comment: @Filburt Okay I get the idea but could you show me an example please? =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you really want is to say:

- Find the current time in Central Europe
- Find 9:10am on the same date
- If 9:10am is after the current time, add a day

So something like:

```
// No need to do this more than once
private static readonly TimeZoneInfo centralEuropeZone = 
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time")

private static DateTime GetUtcResetTime()
{
    // Using UtcNow to make it clear that the system time zone is irrelevant
    var centralEuropeNow = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, centralEuropeZone);
    var centralEuropeResetTime = centralEuropeNow.Date + new TimeSpan(9, 10, 0);
    if (centralEuropeResetTime <= centralEuropeNow)
    {
        centralEuropeResetTime = centralEuropeResetTime.AddDays(1);
    }
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(centralEuropeResetTime, centralEuropeZone);
}
```

I've made that return a *UTC* `DateTime` so that no other code needs to worry about which zone it's in.

Comment: return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(centralEuropeResetTime, centralEuropeZone); returns 7:10 AM instead of 9:10 AM... I have checked variable centralEuropeResetTime , and it is 9:10 AM... Something wrong with the return statement =(

Comment: @User987: It's returning the UTC value - which would indeed be 7:10 UTC. Nothing's wrong... If your code needs to wait until that time, a UTC value is much more useful than a Central Europe one. If you really want the local time instead, just return `centralEuropeResetTime` - but I don't think that's a good idea, as then the caller needs to be aware of the time zone.

Comment: okay got it =) Could you tell me a few scenarios where this would be more userful just so that  I can keep it on my mind ?

Comment: @User987: It means no code other than this method needs to know that the reset time is in Central Europe time. Note that that's information that couldn't be encoded in the `DateTime` itself, so you'd be relying on callers reading the documentation to know how to interpret the `DateTime`, whereas a UTC `DateTime` value has a `Kind` of `Utc`, so you can tell that it *is* UTC. If you were to use a library like Noda Time, you could return a `ZonedDateTime` value that *did* know the specific time zone, so callers wouldn't need to be aware.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the expire date is less that the current date, if so add one day.

```
DateTime expireDate = new DateTime(2018, 7, 30, 22, 0, 0); //for testing

DateTime tomorrowAt0910 = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(9).AddMinutes(10);

if (expireDate.Date < DateTime.Now.Date)
{
    tomorrowAt0910.AddDays(1);
}
```